# A Question about AC Conductivity and Optical Properties

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, solid-state-physics, dielectric

I am studying Omar's solid state physics and have reached the optical part.
Here is a equation that I do not truly understand:

[image]

In it seems that at low frequency the real part of the dielectric function reduces to $\epsilon_{L,r} - \sigma_0\tau/\epsilon_0$ , but instead Omar says that it will vanish to zero in (4. 53). I cannot understand the rationale behind Omar's claim.

Comment: Nevermind. I understand it now.